# Signup/login page working in localhost, but on Heroku I get an Application error (h12/ 503)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, http-status-code-503, application-error

I'm able to signup as a user and login as a user successfully on my local host, but on Heroku I receive an application error. It looks like the request is a timeout issue (H12 / 503 error). I'm confused because the login and signup was working fine about a month ago. I took a break from the project and at the time Heroku was deployed successfully and was working. Now I'm having problems on Heroku and don't know how I can fix the issue or what caused it in the first place.

This is my heroku log -

**2021-04-13T03:30:27.742004+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/auth/signup" host=reciperec-cristina.herokuapp.com request_id=e0e634e0-fd8e-4517-b428-f319e6beaddb fwd="73.202.97.117" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https**

Comment: A "Request timeout" error may involve your network, you should check that first. Try to invoke manually the URL `https://reciperec-cristina.herokuapp.com/auth/signup` from your local host to check if you get a reply and edit your question with the result. If it's not a network problem, check the related listener on the reciperec-cristina.herokuapp.com host (service up ? service log ?) and edit your question with your findings.

Comment: how would i manually invoke the URL? the page itself works. but when I try to sign up as a new user, thats when I get the application error. I'm wondering if I need to update the database